# Possible Rendering Performance Optimizations

Tags: c#, opengl, performance-testing, opentk

I was doing some benchmarking today using C# and OpenTK, just to see how much I could actually render before the framerate dropped. The numbers I got were pretty astronomical, and I am quite happy with the outcome of my tests.

In my project I am loading the blender monkey, which is 968 triangles. I then instance it and render it 100 times. This means that I am rendering 96,800 triangles per frame. This number far exceeds anything that I would need to render during any given scene in my game. And after this I pushed it even further and rendered 2000 monkeys at varying locations. I was now rendering a whopping 1,936,000 (almost 2 million triangles per frame) and the framerate was still locked at 60 frames per second! That number just blew my mind. I pushed it even further and finally the framerate started to drop, but this just means that the limit is roughly 4 million triangles per frame with instancing.

I was just wondering though, because I am using some legacy OpenGL, if this could still be pushed even further—or should I even bother?

For my tests I load the blender monkey model, store it into a display list using the deprecated calls like:

```
modelMeshID = MeshGenerator.Generate( delegate {
            GL.Begin( PrimitiveType.Triangles );
            foreach( Face f in model.Faces ) {
                foreach( ModelVertex p in f.Points ) {
                    Vector3 v = model.Vertices[ p.Vertex ];
                    Vector3 n = model.Normals[ p.Normal ];
                    Vector2 tc = model.TexCoords[ p.TexCoord ];
                    GL.Normal3( n.X , n.Y , n.Z );
                    GL.TexCoord2( tc.Y , tc.X );
                    GL.Vertex3( v.X , v.Y , v.Z );
                }
            }
            GL.End();
        } );
```

and then call that list x amount of times. **My question though, is if I could speed this up if I threw VAO's (Vertex Array Objects) into the display list instead of the old GL.Vertex3 api?** Would this effect performance at all? Or would it create the same outcome with the display list?

Here is a screen grab of a few thousand:

[image]

My system specs:

```
CPU: AMD Athlon IIx4(quad core) 620 2.60 GHz
Graphics Card: AMD Radeon HD 6800
```

Comment: What hardware are you measuring on?

Comment: Never draw `GL` with vertices, [if you can buffer](http://www.opentk.com/doc/graphics/geometry/vertex-arrays) them...

Comment: Hope you realize that this is a very synthetic test that is far from any real-world usage.

Comment: @n0rd Care to elaborate?

Comment: What @n0rd means is that the simplistic geometry, the instancing, the lack of transformations etc etc... allow for a ton of optimizations, not available to most real-world applications, thus speeding things up "artificially", and thus making it not representative of any other application's performance

Comment: Yup, there are no textures, no batching, no shaders. Each of these will take its toll. Also, judging by having only around ~100 of monkey heads in a frame (out of several thousands you claim to draw), 95% of what you draw gets cut in early pipeline stages. So numbers you get don't represent anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question though, is if I could speed this up if I threw VAO's (Vertex Array Objects) into the display list instead of the old GL.Vertex3 api? Would this effect performance at all? Or would it create the same outcome with the display list?

No.

The main problem you're going to run into is, that Display Lists and Vertex Arrays don't go well with each other. Using buffer objects they kind of work, but display lists themself are legacy like the immediate mode drawing API.

However, even if you manage to get the VBO drawing from within a display list right, there'll be slightly an improvement: When compiling the display list the OpenGL driver knows, that everything that is arriving will be "frozen" eventually. This allows for some very aggressive internal optimization; all the geometry data will be packed up into a buffer object on the GPU, state changes are coalesced. AMD is not quite as good at this game as NVidia, but they're not bad either; display lists are heavily used in CAD applications and before ATI addressed the entertainment market, they were focused on CAD, so their display list implementation is not bad at all. If you pack up all the relevant state changes required for a particular drawing call into the display list, then when calling the display list you'll likely drop into the fast path.

> I pushed it even further and finally the framerate started to drop, but this just means that the limit is roughly 4 million triangles per frame with instancing.

What's actually limiting you there is the overhead on calling the display list. I suggest you add a little bit more geometry into the DL and try again.

Display Lists are shockingly efficient. That they got removed from modern OpenGL is mostly because they can be effectively used only with the immediate mode drawing commands. Also recent things like transform feedback and conditional rendering would have been very difficult to integrate into display lists. So they got removed; and rightfully so, because Display Lists are kind of awkward to work with.

Now if you look at Vulkan the essential idea is to set up as much of the drawing commands (state changes, resource bindings and so on) upfront in command buffers and reuse those for varying data. This is like if you could create multiple display lists and have them make babies.

Answer (score 2):

Using vertex lists, `begin` and `end` causes the monkey geometry to be sent to the GPU every iteration, going through PCI-E, which is the slowest memory interface you have during rendering. Also, depending on your GL implementation, every call to GL can have more or less overhead on it's own. If you used buffer objects, all that overhead would be gone, because you only send the monkey over once and then all you need is a draw call every iteration.

However, the monkey geometry is tiny (just a few kb), so sending it over the PCI-E bus (at like 16 GB/s?), plus the few hundred iterations of the "geometry loop", would not even take a millisecond. And even that will not touch your frame-rate because, unless you are explicitly [synchronizing](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Synchronization), it will be completely absorbed by pipelining: the copying and the draw call will run while the GPU is still busy rendering the previous frame. At the time, the GPU starts rendering the next frame, the data is already there.

That is why I am guessing, given you have a fairly optimized GL implementation (good drivers) that using buffer objects, would not yield any speed-up. Note that in the face of bigger and more complex geometry and rendering operations, buffer objects will of course become crucial to performance. Small buffers might even stay cached on chip between draw calls.

Nevertheless, as a serious speed-freak, you definitely want to double-check and verify these sorts of guesstimates :)

Comment: Do you think you could provide an example in code? Even pseudo code would suffice.

Comment: I wrote [a bunch of primitives](https://www.assembla.com/code/squishy-sim/git/nodes/master/Squishy.GL) to make things a bit easier a few years ago (in C++) which are then used by [this sample code](https://www.assembla.com/code/squishy-sim/git/nodes/master/Squishy.GL.Samples/01_my_first_triangle/01_my_first_triangle.cpp) which illustrates the basic program layout of a BO-enabled GL application. Not sure if that helps you? It includes SDL (for a simple GUI and keyboard, mouse input etc.) and ties with GLSL, making it non-minimal though...

Comment: Nitpick; a draw call does not require a round trip to the GPU.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo Fixed it. Thanks for reminding me!

Comment: @Domi: OP is using a DisplayList. When compiling the display list the driver will pack it all up and put it onto the GPU. So this is almost as good as having a VBO.

Comment: @datenwolf Using Display Lists is actually the best logical thing to use for my game. All of the geometry will be static, and what is not static will be used as a VBO instead. But because my geometry will also be dynamic (think kind of like voxels but symmetrical models instead) I will need an easy way of combining them together to form a mesh. I don't understand why Display Lists were deprecated, because of how damn useful they really are. They make it really easy to generate a mesh, or mesh collection. Updating the world only takes a few seconds, too.

Comment: @Krythic You still want to use buffer objects. If you are worried about the hassle, don't write low-level (OpenGL) code yourself. Use a light-weight engine on top of it.